# Laravel JSON API: How to create custom virtual resource from database (for aggregated values)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, json-api

since days I try to figure out how to add a "virtual" resource to my Laravel JSON API (`"cloudcreativity/laravel-json-api": "~2.0"`). To explain:

Lets say I've timerecords in a database table and an Eloquent model, which is used by the JSON API package to transform it automatically to a resource, showing up in `/api/v1/timerecords`. This is working great out of the box, just by adding an Adapter, a Schema and some tiny configuration! Example timerecords:

```
id | customer_id | user_id | ts_start | ts_end | hours | amount_xy | ...
1  | 123         | 5       | 2020-0...| 2020...| 4.5   | 95.2      | ...
2  | 987         | 5       | 2020-0...| 2020...| 2.75  | 32.8      | ...
```

But now I want to have an API endpoint `/api/v1/timeaggregates` with calculated values like `COUNT(id) AS num_records, SUM(hours) AS sum_hours, AVG(amount_xy) AS avg_xy`, where these records can be aggregated by various parameter (or filter to stay in API terms?!), such as:

- "Aggregate values between DATE-FROM and DATE-TO for CUSTOMER=123"
- "Aggregate values for CUSTOMER=123"
- "Aggregate values for CUSTOMER=123 and USER=5"

For sure this resource has to be read-only (GET) because its "virtual". But I could't even come close to anything working. Also searching the whole web results in nothing, which makes me even more wonder as I find such a feature is a pretty common task for an API, isn't it?! What I've tried so far:

- Tried to create a `Eloquent\Collection`. The problem is that I was not able to use this Collection somewhere, since there is only a generic JsonApiController.
- Tried to use a virtual model ([jenssegers/laravel-model](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-model)), but the JSON API expects to receive an Eloquent model
- From other frameworks I know the Repository pattern where I'd implement such aggregate functions, but Laravel seems not to implement this pattern, and even if I'd do it myself, again where to call the Repository functions?
- ... countless other tries

Maybe I'm missing something huge here, or the problem might be using the CloudCreativity package which is not supporting such things (again that would makes me wonder, as the package seems to be very professional with great documentation).

I'd appreachiate if someone of you could give me a hint. Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2):

I've created a somehow ugly workaround. If there is a more clean solution, feel free to enlighten me^^

First I created a "virtual" model, which is not realy virtual as I use an existing "timerecords" table:

```
class Timeaggregate extends Model {
    protected $table = 'timerecords';
}
```

In the resource adapter, I'm overwriting the `queryAll()` method to calculate the aggregated values:

```
    protected function queryAll($query, EncodingParametersInterface $parameters) {
        $this->with($query, $parameters);
        $this->applyFilters($query, collect($parameters->getFilteringParameters()));

        $query->selectRaw('COUNT(id) as count_records')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(hours) AS sum_hours');

        return $query->first();
    }
```

Than in the resource schema getAttributes() method I can simply add the calculated fields to the response using e.g. `$resource->sum_hours`.

Another solution might be to create a non-eloquent resource and manually perform a database query to fill the needed attributes. But I haven't tested that, as I find my needs are so close related to a real existing resource, so it should still be an Eloquent resource in my opinion.